# Give php / apache read access outside of /html

Tags: php, apache, centos

How can I give php and apache read access to a directory outside of /var/www/html?

I'm trying to include the following in a php file:

```
require '/var/www/config/settings.php';
```

Here are the persmissions on config

```
drwxr-xr-x.  2 apache    root 4096 Sep 16 14:02 config
```

And on settings.php

```
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 apache root 306 Sep 16 14:02 settings.php
```

PHP throws the following error:
PHP Warning:  require(/var/www/config/settings.php): failed to open stream: Permission denied in [filename here]

Comment: I don't know if this will help, but try `sudo chown -R root:root config`

Comment: I tried that, no luck.

Comment: From the question, obviously apache user is having full permission over config folder as well as settings.php file. Now see what is your PHP handler... the user that run PHP files doesn't have permission to read that file... for quick work around, try _chmod o+rwx config_ and _chmod o+rwx settings.php_ see if that helps, otherwise let us know your PHP handler

Comment: @LeoPrince I got it to work and added an answer. I'm not sure what actually fixed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After fighting it and trying the suggestions here I got it to work but don't understand why...

What I did to troubleshoot...

I cd'ed into the config directory then I created a new file using vim and named it test.php

then: chown apache test.php

Changed the php script that was including it to test.php instead of settings.php

THAT WORKED!! WHY? Both files have the exact same permissions and ownerships. I changed it back to settings.php and it failed again.

I then copied the contents of settings.php into test.php, deleted settings.php and renamed test.php->settings.php

Now I'm in business.

If someone could explain what happened that would be great.

Answer (score 0):

sudoing chown will not work, this has been set in your apache's document root entry

you need to create 2 entries. 1 being this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot  /var/www/html
ServerName www.yourdomain.com

# Other directives here

</VirtualHost>
```

and for this /var/www/config/settings.php you need to create this entry

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot  /var/www/config
ServerName www.yourdomain.com

# Other directives here

</VirtualHost>
```

This is how web servers work, in order to gain access to another document root or / 
when you call it in the url it looks at **DocumentRoot**

Make sure to restart apache after you do that to take changes in effect.